# How to filter items by a field in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

```
"Products" : {
    "DateTime" : {
      "category" : "Mobile Phones",
      "pid" : "",
      "pname" : "",
      "price" : "",
    }
  }
```

Hello I am developing an android app using firebase. I am able to list all products in my firebase database. However, I would like to show products based on the category (ex: `Mobile Phones`, `Tablets` etc). How do I do this?

Comment: Hi Sadusha Nadeesh welcome to stackoverflow. Please add some details and code to your question this will help answerer to understand your question. Please have look at this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a compound query like:

```
Query products = db.collection("Products/DateTime").whereEqualTo("category", YOUR_CATEGORY);
```

Check more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)